# insert data into dictionary [C#]

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a problem: how can I solve the problem that I can not insert entries into the dictionary (this is the C # programming language).
What to do about it? And how can I solve the problem?

Code fragment:

```
        public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        public static int CTR = 1;
        public  Customer C  { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int,Customer> myd = new Dictionary<int, Customer>();
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (CTR > 1)
            {
            C = myd.Last().Value;
            return View(C);
            }
            else
            {
            return View();

            }
        }

    public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Submit()
        {
            Customer c = this.C;
            CTR++;
            myd.Add(CTR,c);
            return View("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult ShowAll()
        {

            return View(myd.Last().Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *problem that I can not insert entries into the dictionary* Why can't you insert entries in a dictionary?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Show us your code so that we can see how you are trying to do this. We can't help if we can't see what is going wrong.

Comment: If I had to guess, you probably want your dictionary to be `static`.

Comment: The above code is a controller code in asp.net mvc 5

Comment: What happens when you hit the break point in the Submit action?

Comment: Is Submit being hit? Do you get a 200 response back? Any errors?

Comment: No wonder why you get confused, with that formatting even Alan Turing himself would get confused.

Comment: I have several errors:
What the Visual Studio shows me is the above error:System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You are not doing anything in Add, maybe you should be calling Submit instead. You also need to store your variables between calls, either in a database or static/global space. Sessions are not a great place to store things since they only persist temporarily and you don't know how long you need to store things.

Comment: Look up what a null reference exception is and it should be pretty easy to fix. It looks like your Customer object is the culprit.

Comment: Are you sure that this.c is not undefined?

Comment: Looks like you might need a Customer instance.

Answer (score 0):

MVC controller is created each time a new Web request hits it, so your fields will always be re-created. Consider using static fields